# JS: How Do I make this script smaller. Random object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Been learning Javascript through some tutorials the last couple of months (code academy/ free code camp etc) and want to use what I've learnt to build something on my own.

I've built a Random number generator that pushes 5 random numbers into an object with 5 empty arrays in it. The script works. But I think it could be cleaner and a lot less code. I'm just not sure how to do that.

Any advice here would be greatly appreciated, as I'm still learning.

(I've realised that there is also a bug in here that would mean there's a chance that one of the "tickets" has a duplicated number in it. - need to address that at some point {haha} )

here's my script:

```js
function RanNum(max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * max)
}
const LOTO_ARRAY = 5;
const lotto1Array = [];
const lotto2Array = [];
const lotto3Array = [];
const lotto4Array = [];
const lotto5Array = [];

for (let i = 0; i<LOTO_ARRAY; i++){
    lotto1Array.push(RanNum(56))
    lotto2Array.push(RanNum(56))
    lotto3Array.push(RanNum(56))
    lotto4Array.push(RanNum(56))
    lotto5Array.push(RanNum(56))
}
   

var ticket = {
    "ticket one" : [],
    "ticket two" : [],
    "ticket three" : [],
    "ticket four" : [],
    "ticket five" : []
};

ticket["ticket one"] = lotto1Array
ticket["ticket two"] = lotto2Array
ticket["ticket three"] = lotto3Array
ticket["ticket four"] = lotto4Array
ticket["ticket five"] = lotto5Array

console.log(ticket);
```

Comment: Why is `ticket` an object? Why not another array? With that you can push as many "tickets" as you like without unnecessary dummy properties (`"ticket ..."`).

Comment: Have a look at `for...in...` or `Object.keys()`. Use them to iterate over the properties in `ticket` and you can get rid of the `lottoXArray`s.

Answer (score 1):

You can pull out getTicket to another function - and then use this to generate each ticket.

You can also use Array.from to create an array with some items in it. The first argument can be used to initiailise the length of the array, and the second argument is a function which returns the value in each item in the array.

Example:

```js
Array.from({ length: 4}, () => 'foo') // Gives ['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo];
```

You can then get a lot of a rid of intermediate arrays - and create the object you want directly.

```js
const TICKET_SIZE = 5;
const MAX_LOTTO_NUMBER = 56;

function getRandomNumber(max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * max)
}

// Gets a ticket of size 
function getTicket() {
  return Array.from({ length: size }, () => getRandomNumber(MAX_LOTTO_NUMBER));
}

const ticket = {
  "ticket one" : getTicket(),
  "ticket two" : getTicket(),
  "ticket three" : getTicket(),
  "ticket four" : getTicket(),
  "ticket five" : getTicket(),
};

console.log(ticket);
```

Comment: Thank you for this.  Didn't know about the .from method! This is really helpful

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the input guys, really helpful for me to understand different approaches to using JS.

I went back and reworked my script. I ended up replacing the "functions" with "Arrow  Functions"  - from a readability POV is this a good move or no?

```js
randomNumber = (max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * max);

getTicket  = () => Array.from({ length: 5 }, () => randomNumber(56));

getStarNumber = () => Array.from({ length: 2 }, () => randomNumber(10));

const ticket = {
    "Ticket One" : getTicket() + " | " + getStarNumber(),
    "Ticket Two" : getTicket() + " | " + getStarNumber(),
    "Ticket Three" : getTicket() + " | " + getStarNumber(),
    "Ticket Four" : getTicket() + " | " + getStarNumber(),
    "Ticket Five" : getTicket() + " | " + getStarNumber(),
}
console.log(ticket)
```

Comment: I think this is a great move, it's a huge improvement from your original post; clean, concise and readable. You could possibly a function to encompass the whole `getTicket() + " | " + getStarNumber()` string.

Comment: agreed - i.e `const createTicket = () => getTicket() + " | " + getStarNumber();`

One thing to note on your current approach is that by not providing `const` before the function assignments is that you're adding them to global scope which I wouldn't recommend - so I'd suggest for example `const getStarNumber = () => Array.from({ length: 2 }, () => randomNumber(10));` instead